# How to integrate Fuelux repeater in Aurelia?

Tags: fuelux

I try to integrate Fuelux repeater in Aurelia app.  The problem is that the columns are not rendering :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. The problem was "columns" are defined in the Aurelia class. But in the ajax callback, "this" is undefined, the solution was to bind :

```
defineRepeater() {
    let __this = this;
    // initialize the repeater
    ($('#myRepeater') as any).repeater({
        //init stuff
        dataSource: __this.customDataSource.bind(__this);
    });
}

customDataSource(options: any, callback) {
    let __this = this;
    ...
    columns: __this.columns
    ...
}
```